# Xamarin Forms Entry boxes loses their cursor position with custom keypad

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am attempting to create a calculator app with a custom keypad using the MVVM pattern. The calculator has four entry boxes and I am suppressing the phone's keyboard from showing by using a custom renderer. I have noticed that the entrees lose their cursor position when I type numbers in an entry, change the cursor position manually by tapping in another position, and start typing again. When I start typing again, the initial character goes into the correct position, but any characters after that goes at the beginning of the string which means the cursor position is zero.

I cannot figure out what is resetting the cursor position. I am keeping track of the cursor position through binding. Here is a small snippet from my code below. So if EntryOne is Selected(Has Focus) and you start typing, the GetText method is called and I am passing in the cursor position by reference. The text that already exists in the Entry is separated into two parts. All the characters in front of the cursor position are part one and all the characters after the cursor position is part two. The parameter is the number the user pressed. All three strings are concatenated together to display the new text in the Entry box. If I use the phone’s keyboard I do not have this issue. So I know it is possible.

Please see the app attached and let me know if more info is needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!!!

```
EntryOneText = GetText(EntryOneText, parameter, ref _entryOneCursorIndex);
private string GetText(string text, string parameter, ref int cursorPosition)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
     {
       string partOne = text.Substring(0, cursorPosition);
       string partTwo = text.Substring(cursorPosition, (text.Length - cursorPosition));
       cursorPosition++;
       return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", partOne, parameter, partTwo);
     }
     cursorPosition++;
     return parameter;
}
```

[EntryCursorPositionTest](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CjoT10UcWAqahrE4ppDv_DaOf8yJ6u9a/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: When you change the cursor position manually and set the text, the entry seems loses focus. Then the _entryOneCursorIndex is set to 0. Will update you when find a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking forward to your solution.

Comment: Well, does not find a solution so far. Every time I change the cursor position manually, the _entryOneCursorIndex will be reset. And the reset happens after you call GetText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alessandro Caliaro. He provided an answer for me on the Xamarin Forms Forum.

```
private void EntryOne_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
  _mainViewModel.SelectedEntry = 1;
  _mainViewModel.EntryOneCursorIndex = ((Entry)sender).CursorPosition;
}

public ICommand NumericCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new Command<string>((string parameter) =>
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter))
      {
        switch (SelectedEntry)
        {
          case 1:
                    if (EntryOneText == null)
                        EntryOneText = "";
                    int save = EntryOneCursorIndex;
                    EntryOneText = EntryOneText.Insert(save, parameter);
                    EntryOneCursorIndex = save + 1;
              //EntryOneText = GetText(EntryOneText, parameter, ref _entryOneCursorIndex);
            break;
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) which will help more people with same problem:).